# ASP.NET MVC Concurrency with RowVersion in Edit Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, concurrency

I'm wanting to do a simple edit form for our Issue Tracking app.  For simplicity, the HttpGet Edit action looks something like this:

```
    // Issues/Edit/12
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var thisIssue = edmx.Issues.First(i => i.IssueID == id);
        return View(thisIssue);
    }
```

and then the HttpPost action looks something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection form)
    {
        // this is the dumb part where I grab the object before I update it.
        // concurrency is sidestepped here.
        var thisIssue = edmx.Issues.Single(c => c.IssueID == id);

        TryUpdateModel(thisIssue);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            edmx.SaveChanges();

            TempData["message"] = string.Format("Issue #{0} successfully modified.", id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(thisIssue);
    }
```

Which works wonderfully.  However, the concurrency check doesn't work because in the Post, I'm re-retreiving the current entity right before I attempt to update it.  However, with EF, I don't know how to use the fanciness of `SaveChanges()` but attach my `thisIssue` to the context.  I tried to call `edmx.Issues.Attach(thisIssue)` but I get

```
The object cannot be attached because it is already in the object context. An object can only be reattached when it is in an unchanged state.
```

How do I handle concurrency in MVC with EF and/or how do I properly `Attach` my edited object to the context?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are doing is tricky, but can be made to work. Let's presume your timestamp field is called `ConcurrencyToken`. Obviously, you must include this value in the View and submit it with your form.  But you can't simply assign that to the value to `thisIssue.ConcurrencyToken` in the POST because the EF will remember both the "old" value (the value you fetched from the DB with your call to `Single()` as well as the "new" value (from your form) and use the "old" value in the `WHERE` clause. So you need to lie to the EF and assign the correct value. Try this:

```
    var thisIssue = edmx.Issues.Single(c => c.IssueID == id);
    TryUpdateModel(thisIssue); // assign ConcurrencyToken
    var ose = Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entityToUpdate);
    ose.AcceptChanges();       // pretend object is unchanged
    TryUpdateModel(thisIssue); // assign rest of properties
```

You can optimize this by binding only `ConcurrencyToken` instead of calling `TryUpdateModel` twice, but this should get you started.

Comment: well, that sure works, but it definitely feels kludgy.  Is there not a way to just say this is my issue object; attach this issue object to issue #12 and update issue #12 with the values stored here?  That way, it puts it on the database to make sure that issue #12 still has the same timestamp...

Also, can you elaborate further on how I'd only bind the ConcurrencyToken field?

Comment: You bind only one field by passing a whitelist; there's an overload for that. To do what you ask regarding updating, you'd create a stub object, attach it to the context, and update it. This prevents fetching the newer `ConcurrencyToken` from the DB.

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure I'm just being dense, but can you spell out something on how to stub something out and attach it.  I tried this and it didnt work

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Edit(int id, Issue issue)
  {

   Issue newIssue = new Issue();
   newIssue.IssueID = id;
   newIssue.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("MayflyEntities.Issues", "IssueID", id);
   edmx.Issues.Attach(newIssue);
   newIssue = issue;
   edmx.SaveChanges();
  }

Comment: Here's an example: http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/06/19/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities.aspx

Answer (score 6):

An example of performing optimistic concurrency compatible updates using EF5 follows (the method comes from a repository.)  It is assumed that the Entity defines Timestamp with `[ConcurrencyCheck]`.  The concurrency exception occurs upon calling `DbContext.SaveChanges()`.

```
public TEntity Update(TEntity entity)
{
    var attached = this.GetById(entity.Id);
    if (attached == null)
    {
        throw new MvcBootstrapDataException("{0} with Id = {1} does not exist.".F(typeof(TEntity).Description(), entity.Id));
    }

    var entry = this.Context.Entry(attached);

    // The Timestamp must be in the original values for optimistic concurrency checking to occur.
    // Otherwise the context knows that the Timestamp has been modified in the context
    entry.OriginalValues["Timestamp"] = entity.Timestamp;

    entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);

    attached.Modified = DateTime.Now;

    return attached;
}
```

Comment: Calr, your solution is better than the one posted by Craig, because it goes straight to updating the property we want. Since I am working with an abstract and generic implementation of an Entity list, I created a simpler function that let me update any property of any entity (I just make sure I only use it on retrieved entities from DB): 

`public virtual void UpdateEntityOriginalValue(T entity, string property, object value)
        {
            var entry = _entities.Entry(entity);
            entry.OriginalValues[property] = value;
        }`