# OptimisticConcurrencyException is not thrown allthough values are different

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I have an issue where OptimisticConcurrencyException is not thrown, I have this code that is run on my HttpPost Edit

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(IncidentViewModel incidentViewModel)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Incident incident;
            if (IncidentViewModel.TryParse(incidentViewModel, out incident))
            {
                Incident entry = _incidentManager.Find(entity => entity.Id == incident.Id);
                if(incident.Version != entry.Version)
                {
                }
```

If I then open 2 browsers and force an OptimisticConcurrencyException by editing at the same time, the incident.Version and entry.Version have different values, but the exception is NOT thrown.

In my .edmx file the Version property is set to "StoreGeneratedPattern" = Computed and Concurrency Mode = Fixed. The type is Timestamp (Binary)

Read this post [OptimisticConcurrencyException Does Not Work in Entity Framework In Certain Situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402586/optimisticconcurrencyexception-does-not-work-in-entity-framework-in-certain-situ) but that didnt really shed light on the issue (I didnt get it)

Edit: The .edmx file and the controller using it is in 2 seperate projects but same solution

Edit:
This is my update method in my manager

```
public virtual void Update(T updatedEntry)
    {
        if (updatedEntry == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("updatedEntry");
        RequiredData(updatedEntry);
        Repository.Update(updatedEntry);
        Repository.Commit();
    }
```

My repository update and commit is:

```
public void Update(T entity)
    {
        object originalItem;
        var key = Context.CreateEntityKey(Context.GetEntitySet<T>().Name, entity);

        if (Context.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out originalItem))
        {
            Context.ApplyCurrentValues(key.EntitySetName, entity);
        }
    }

public int Commit()
    {
        var saveValue = Context.SaveChanges();
        return saveValue;
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show how do you actually save your entity.

Comment: Check my explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946883/asp-net-mvc-entity-framework-with-concurrency-check/5947054#5947054) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327649/entity-framework-optimistic-concurrency-exception-not-occuring/5327770#5327770). I guess it is duplicate.