# Locking the record and unlocking

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, locking

I am new to this web application development and I have task to do. This probably would be some kind of a service (probably WCF at least this is my idea) which will be responsible for locking and unlocking records in db. I'm searching for some kind of best practices and/or tools which wil do that. By tools I mean the opensource solutions or something like that. The case is that what to do when user i.e closes the browser, or one is editing the record and the other one also edit the record, what we should do in this case. I hope this is understandable what I want to accomplish. From what that I know the problem with locks is that they are statless so this is some kind of an issue but I don't know what kind :) Thank you in advance for your help and time :)

ps. I've tried to google this in Stack..but all I get is the lock keyword in c# and in google there are soultions but not quite what I am looking for. Maybe I'm typing in the wrong keywords...I don't know

Answer (score 3):

> I'm searching for some kind of best practices

Don't do this. **Do not write applications that explicitly lock and unlock data in the database**. There is absolutely 0 (zero) valid scenarios for this.

I recommend you read about [optimistic concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control).

Also read [Entity Framework Optimistic Concurrency Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx) and [Anti-Pattern #3: Mishandled Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882522.aspx#id0420025).

Comment: thank you I wil read this :) so if there are anymore ideas I'll gladely read about this.

Answer (score 0):

On the whole, locking records in a database is a really dangerous thing to do - especially through a service that isn't related to the actual data manipulation process. If other programs encounter that locked record and want to write to it, they tend to have to deal with exotic synchronisation issues - do they wait? Do they discard the changes they wanted to write?

In most database engines, the process that's been locked just waits - before you know it, you can have dozens or hundreds of suspended database tasks, all waiting for the lock to be released.

As Remus Rusanu writes, you should read up on optimistic concurrency control - this is the best practice for transactional web applications. It's supported by the MS Entity Framework (assuming your app is built using .Net); code example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775450/asp-net-mvc-concurrency-with-rowversion-in-edit-action/2775887#2775887).

Comment: thank you for your time and all the advices of course I've read about this but it seems that we have some other way. We don't use for now entity framework. I've heard from my friends at work that optimistic concurrency control can't be used here as we have a server farm. This causes the problem that we don't know which server we will "ask" and what I've heard the OCC is not valid here. So we create a table on DB that will register the info about the user and a date of lock, and based on that the service will return info whether the lock is set, someone locked or lock should be extended ..